# Extending existing integration to permit phone payments

Tags: integration, opayo

I have developed an online ticketing application that uses a simple form integration - it's been running successfully for some years.

I have been asked to extend this so that it can be used for phone payments.

The reason for this is that the ticketing application has a great many options before the final price is arrived at so the people taking the call could use the same software (with minor modifications).

I can't see any options in the integrations for doing anything like this. It's all for customer payments.

Can anybody tell me if this is possible (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding.  It comes down to `AccountType` when you make your request to Sage Pay.

That accepts three different values:

- E - use ecommerce account
- M - use MOTO (mail order/telephone order) account
- C - use continuous authority account.

Depending on your merchant bank and what you requested when you set up your merchant accounts, you'll have a merchant account for each.  Sage Pay will send your request to the correct merchant account.  This is key because if you use M, you'll not be expected to use 3D secure for the card - and the expectation is that it will be you processing the card, not the customer.

Comment: Unless I am missing your meaning, the Form Protocol doesn't have a field called 'AccountType'. Am I to assume that a different integration is needed to do this?

I'm struggling a bit here... I don't know anything about these payment types (those E, M, C terms don't mean a thing to me). I'm just the developer. I suppose I'm going back to the client and asking them to speak to SagePay and/or their bank (I had nothing to do with that bit).

Comment: I'm not sure specifically with the Forms integration, I've tended to lean towards Server and Direct.  But yes - I would definitely go back to your client to make sure they have merchant account set up for MOTO and this is configured in Sage Pay (sage pay will know these things) - this will then behave correctly when you try and take the payment through yourself - rather than the cardholder themselves.